# An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the ImportImage operation: The service role vmimport does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-vm-import

I am trying to import a disk image into AWS, for EC2 instance launching. I follow the guide as stated and fulfill all the prerequisites as stated. However I am faced with an error that I've been trying (unsuccessfully) to debug. The error is as follows. 
`An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the ImportImage operation: The service role vmimport provided does not exist or does not have sufficient permissions`
 However when I check the permissions of the vmimport role it has all necessary permissions for EC2 and S3! My aws cli user also has full privileges to EC2 and S3. I've tried many different solutions to this problem, including, 1. Making the S3 bucket public, 2. Adding an access policy so that my AWS cli user had permissions to access the bucket. Everything I have tried still returns this exact same error message... I'm thinking there might be a region problem? I'm using us-east-2 in my AWS cli user configuration, and in the S3 buckets region. Is there something else I have not considered?
P.S. I'm trying to import an OVA 1 format vm image.

Here is my trust policy

```
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": { "Service": "vmie.amazonaws.com" },
         "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
         "Condition": {
            "StringEquals":{
               "sts:Externaloid": "vmimport"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

and my roles policy

```
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket" 
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::MY-IMPORT-BUCKET",
            "arn:aws:s3:::MY-IMPORT-BUCKET/*"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetBucketAcl"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::MY-EXPORT-BUCKET",
            "arn:aws:s3:::MY-EXPORT-BUCKET/*"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "ec2:ModifySnapshotAttribute",
            "ec2:CopySnapshot",
            "ec2:RegisterImage",
            "ec2:Describe*"
         ],
         "Resource": "*"
      }
   ]
}
```

And finally the containers.json

```
[
  {
    "Description": "My Special OVA",
    "Format": "ova",
    "Url": "s3://MY-IMPORT-BUCKET/VM.ova"
  }
]
```

**UPDATE:** After investigating the problem further, I found that the role vmimport last access was "Not accessed", i.e. never, meaning that the role is not even being attempted to be used! So this error is clearly saying that it does not exist (it can't find the service role). In the final command there is nothing in the command that suggests that vmimport is going to be used, neither in the containers.json . I thought this was the purpose of allowing vmie.amazonaws.com to take control. Clearly it isn't assuming the role, so I need to investigate into this and sts.

Comment: Can you please share the policies for the `vmimport` role?

Comment: I have added the files I used. Also note that I can verify that in the AWS management console that all these permissions are indeed included with the vmimport role. The service is also associated with the role as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your(my) Trust Policy.json file. If you notice the conditions for it to assume the role, is that the External**o**id must be equal to vmimport. There is an added ***o*** in the attribute that it is checking, this will always be false and so vmie can never assume the role. Remove the o from the trust policy and try again and your policy works.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same scenario, you need to create vmimport role as described here (AWS docs):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/required-permissions.html